# Verifying that this old ubuntu (16.04.6) ISO is official

Tags: iso, downloads

I just downloaded a .torrent file from ubuntu.com, however there's no way to download that file from https. So I'm looking for a way to confirm that my ubuntu ISO is official. Its sha256sum is below:

```
sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso 
eecb9c8160cdb08adf0c2f17daa1d403f5a55f14a856a5973f32f267eb9db039  ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso
```

Can somebody point me to an official place (https) from ubuntu.com where I can confirm (at least with a decent degree of condifence) that this is indeed an oficial ISO?

(newer images have their sha256 sums given through https by ubuntu.com in the moment of download, but not this)

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

For how to use verify using gpg & sha256, please see https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

(*also note there is not a single ISO, there are desktop, server, network alternate... let alone different architectures..*)

You can browse downloads at  http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.6/
Or if you just want to grab the sha256sums (*for x86, x86_64, server, desktop*) http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.6/SHA256SUMS